# How to reset a gazebo world including actors positions

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there, community. I've created a gazebo simulation world with five human actors. I'd want to reset the simulation and the world, as well as each actor's position. However, after calling the reset simulation and reset world ros services, the actor plugin no longer works, and the actors remain stucked and overlapping one another. Is it possible to reset everything in Gazebo, including the actors' plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396312/how-to-reset-a-gazebo-world-including-actors-positions/) by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2022-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear community, the problem is solved by simply calling the ActorPlugin->Reset() inside the plugin (C++) source code. Do not forget to change the etiquette of the the Reset() method from protected: to public: so that it will be callable by the outside. Finally, calling the /gazebo/reset_simulation rosservice will result in resetting the plugin that controls those actors.

---

Originally posted by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) with karma: 42 on 2022-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-02-19**:
Thank you for sharing!

**Comment by [Hirak231992](https://answers.ros.org/users/61646/hirak231992/) on 2022-09-27**:
where do you set the Reset() function. Could you kindly elaborate. I am facing the same issue.

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2022-09-27**:
Hi, you have to just override it just define the function inside your plugin source code :

void pluginClass::Reset()
{
.......
Do here whatever you want to reset anything ....
....
}

**Comment by [Hirak231992](https://answers.ros.org/users/61646/hirak231992/) on 2022-09-27**:
I have updated the mass of the object in runtime by writing a custom modelplugin. Could you kindly suggest where I should place my overriding function. I have attached the code and asked for it in the forum too. I would be very grateful if you could kindly see it.

[link text](https://answers.ros.org/question/407020/resetting-the-simulation-after-writing-custom-model-plugin-how-to-reset-model-plugin/)

**Comment by [seif_seghiri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60505/seif_seghiri/) on 2022-09-28**:
put this definition on the source file (your_plugin.cpp)

```
void yourPluginClass::Reset() { ...... }
```

after adding this to the class public virtual methods declaration:

```
public: virtual void Reset();
```